# Pandas aggregations on previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to compute some aggregations (here: mean and standard deviation) on my dataframe, but on rows where the date is before the last date in the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"day": ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-03'],
                        "country": ["France", "Brazil", "France", "Brazil", "France", "Brazil", ],
                        "n": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    })
print(df)
          day country  n
0  2021-01-01  France  1
1  2021-01-01  Brazil  2
2  2021-01-02  France  3
3  2021-01-02  Brazil  4
4  2021-01-03  France  5
5  2021-01-03  Brazil  6
```

What I would like:

```
     country  mean std
0  France     2    1.4142
1  Brazil     3    1.4142
```

I tried

```
mean = df.groupby("country")["n"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].mean())
std = df.groupby("country")["n"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].std())
```

But it feels very un-pandas to do it this way.

Comment: `df[df.day != df.day.max()].groupby('country').n.mean()`?